# How can i rewrite the following java code better way?

Tags: java

I am having a small piece of java code. I would like to rewrite the following code in a more constructive way and elegant way . how can i achieve it .?

```
boolean ifJobTypeIsProfileAndAccountTypeIsNotInternal(PrimecastAccount primecastAccount,Job job) { 
if( job.getProfile() != null && job.getContactList() == null && job.getParameterisedContactList() == null) {
 return true;
} else if (job.getProfile() == null && job.getContactList() != null && job.getParameterisedContactList() == null) {
 return false;
} else if (job.getProfile() == null && job.getContactList() == null && job.getParameterisedContactList() != null) {
 return false;
} else if (job.getProfile() == null && job.getContactList() == null && job.getParameterisedContactList() == null) {
  log.error("Either a contact list, parameterised contact list or profile not found for the flight : {}", job );
  throw new RuntimeException("Either a contact list, parameterised contact list or profile not found for the flight");
} else {
  log.error("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight : {}", job );
  throw new RuntimeException("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight");
}

return true;

}
```

thank you so much
appreciate any help

Comment: First small but nevertheless very important improvements: 1) remove the first argument that is not used anywhere in the method body 2) indent properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Java 8 or higher you can use streams, `Objects#nonNull` and `Objects#isNull`

```
public boolean isProfileTypeJobWithNotInternalAccountType(Job job){
    var profile  = job.getProfile();
    var contList = job.getContactList();
    var paCoList = job.getParameterisedContactList();
    
    var allNull = Stream.of(profile,contList,paCoList).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
    var twoNotNull = Stream.of(profile,contList,paCoList).filter(Objects::nonNull).count() > 1;
    
    if(allNull){
        log.error("Either a contact list, parameterised contact list or profile not found for the flight : {}", job );
        throw new RuntimeException("Either a contact list, parameterised contact list or profile not found for the flight");
    }
    if(twoNotNull){            
        log.error("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight : {}", job );
        throw new RuntimeException("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight");
    }
    return Objects.nonNull(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First handle the possible errors. After that, the remaining cases are very easy to clean up here.

```
boolean ifJobTypeIsProfileAndAccountTypeIsNotInternal(PrimecastAccount primecastAccount,Job job) { 

    if (job.getProfile() == null && job.getContactList() == null && job.getParameterisedContactList() == null) {
      log.error("Neither a contact list, parameterised contact list, nor profile found for the flight : {}", job );
      throw new RuntimeException("Neither a contact list, parameterised contact list, nor profile found for the flight");
    } 
    if (job.getProfile() != null && (job.getContactList() != null || job.getParameterisedContactList() != null)){
      log.error("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight : {}", job );
      throw new RuntimeException("Found both contact list/parameterised list and profile for the flight");
    }
    
    return job.getProfile() != null;
}
```

Sadly you won't get around the error conditions.

Comment: I just realized I forgot `job.getProfile() == null && job.getContactList() != null && job.getParameterizedContactList() != null` as an exception thrower. Which would be a third if and not much prettier than the original. Might have to think about it a bit more but don't have the time right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
static boolean if2(Job job) {
        boolean eitherContactPresent = job.getContactList() == null || job.getParameterisedContactList() == null;
        boolean bothContactAbsent = job.getContactList() == null && job.getParameterisedContactList() == null;
        if (job.getProfile() != null) {
            if (bothContactAbsent) return true;
            else if (!eitherContactPresent) throw new RuntimeException("ALL present");
        }
        if (bothContactAbsent) throw new RuntimeException("None present");
        return false;
    }
```